# Vue built a product to upload to the server

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, build

I'm building a web page for an event using bootstrap-vue (I started the projet with `vue init bootstrap-vue/webpack my-project`). I've used `vue-build prod` to compose and uploaded the whole folder to my server using filezilla. The problem is that the website is not fine, just a part of it is sawn.

Answer (score 0):

Can you formulate the question differently? Its hard to find out what it is exactly you mean with

> The problem is that the website is not fine, just a part of it is
>   sawn.

What does the console in your browser tell you? Vue has alot of debugging tools built in, so maybe you can post the console output, then we can tell a bit more..

Comment: As far as i can see you didnt build it correct. There is no vue instance loaded. Do you use NPM package manager?
In windows you can do this:
cd to path of bootstrap-vue project, then `NPM  RUN BUILD` will create a folder `DIST` where the files are.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first project in Vue and I don't  know exactly what do you refer. I've composed it using the command line and any information appears except the has, the version and two time parameters.The website is in this link http://thegraph.es/Citython/ and the code of the whole project is https://github.com/MGijon/Citython/tree/master/web

Comment: I've try to use the content of the `dist` folder and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I dont know what the problem is sorry.. I cant seem to get it to work either.. local works fine, but after building i cant get it to work..

Comment: This is not an answer; it should have been a comment on the original post. The original poster should update the question with more information.